# Initialize dataframe with a constant

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, initialization

Initializing dataframe with a constant value does not work,

```
pd.DataFrame(0, index=[1,2,3])      # doesnt work!
    # OR
pd.DataFrame(0)                     # doesnt work!
```

whereas I observe that

> (1) Initializing Series with a constant value works

```
pd.Series(0, index=[1,2,3])         # Works fine!
```

> (2) Initializing DataFrame with None works

```
pd.DataFrame(None, index=[1,2,3])   # Works fine!
```

> (3) Initializing DataFrame when index and columns are not provided works

```
pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3])             # Works fine!
pd.DataFrame([0])                   # Works fine!
```

Does anyone know why?

I am keen to know more from a design consideration, rather than an answer like "if you check the pandas code, you'd see that it fails one of the checks where the data dimension is expected to be >1.. blah blah".

I think it should just work intuitively (considering that pandas is intelligent in assigning a default col and index when not provided, and also guesses the dimensions from the data given).

May be there is some reason for this behaviour but can't figure.

Answer (score 13):

A `pd.DataFrame` is 2-dimensional.  When you specify

```
pd.DataFrame(0, index=[1, 2, 3])
```

You are telling the constructor to assign `0` to every row with indices `1`, `2`, and `3`.  But what are the columns?  You didn't define any columns.

You can do two things

**Option 1**
*specify your columns*

```
pd.DataFrame(0, index=[1, 2, 3], columns=['x', 'y'])

   x  y
1  0  0
2  0  0
3  0  0
```

---

**Option 2**
*pass a list of values*

```
pd.DataFrame([[0]], index=[1, 2, 3])

   0
1  0
2  0
3  0
```